# How to print out different elements from an array depending on the content of another array?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

So, what I want to do is to have this simple "log in" with 4 users (each associated with a different password), after "granting" access to the users, each can see different elements from the 'info' array (e.g. User1 can see all four elements, User2 can see only three, User3 can see 2 elements, and User4 can see only one).

This is my main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Data {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String username;
        String password;

        System.out.println("LOG IN");

        System.out.println("User: ");
        username = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Password: ");
        password = input.nextLine();

        Users check = new Users(username, password);

        if (check.access())
        System.out.println("WELCOME");
        else
        System.out.println("ACCESS DENIED");
    }
}
```

And this is my Users class:

```
public class Users {
    private String username;
    private String password;        
    private String[][] accounts = {{"user1","pass1"},{"user2","pass2"},
{"user3","pass3"},{"user4","pass4"}};


    public Users (String user, String pass){
        username = user;
        password = pass;
    }

    public boolean access() {
        if ((username.equals(accounts[0][0])) && (password.equals(accounts[0][1])))
            return true;  
        if ((username.equals(accounts[1][0])) && (password.equals(accounts[1][1])))
            return true;
        if ((username.equals(accounts[2][0])) && (password.equals(accounts[2][1])))
            return true;
        if ((username.equals(accounts[3][0])) && (password.equals(accounts[3][1])))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
        }
        public static String [] info = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
    }
```

My question is, how do I print out A, B, C and/or D depending of it's User1 or User2, etc?

Comment: Where do you want to print A, B..etc? Within the `access()` method or the `main()` method?

Comment: Within the main() method.

Comment: A `Map` would be a better data structure

Comment: I agree with @MadProgrammer but the OP may be constrained to use arrays only (could be an assignment)

Comment: @paisanco Context is king :P

Comment: Your `Users` class does not seem to be object oriented.

Comment: We're allowed to use anything as long as it works, but I have little experience with Maps and HashMaps, how would that work out?

Comment: @MadProgrammer How would you do it using `Map`?

Comment: Group the information for each user into some kind structure (maybe a `List`), place each group into the `Map` through some key which can easily mapped to a user

Comment: @MadProgrammer And how do you compare the user's input in the log in with the info in the `List`?

Comment: @LeonHorka That's where the "key" comes into play, you need to be able to map from the user to a "entry"/"key" in the `Map`

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to add a list of integers to the `Users` class:

```
List<Integer> infoRights;
```

This list can store the indices of the `info[]` array to which a given user has rights.  In this case, these integer values would almost be acting like keys into the `info[]` array.

```
public class Users {
    private static String [] info = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
    private List<Integer> infoRights;

    public void printInfo() {
        String info = "";
        for (int right : infoRights) {
            info += right;
        }
        System.out.println(info);
    }

    // getters and setters to manage infoRights
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use more object oriented approach, as was mentioned in comments. Create `UserService`, which will check user credentials and return user info if credentials are correct. Please see code below as rough example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class UserService {

    private static class UserDetails {
        private final String password;
        private final String info;

        private UserDetails(String password, String info) {
            this.password = password;
            this.info = info;
        }

        public String getInfo() {
            return info;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
    }

    private final Map<String, UserDetails> userDetails = new HashMap<>();

    public UserService() {
        userDetails.put("user1", new UserDetails("pass1", "A"));
        userDetails.put("user2", new UserDetails("pass2", "B"));
        userDetails.put("user3", new UserDetails("pass3", "C"));
        userDetails.put("user4", new UserDetails("pass4", "D"));
    }

    public UserDetails checkCredentials(String username, String password) {
        UserDetails details = userDetails.get(username);
        if (details == null || !details.password.equals(password)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return details;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll check if user credentials are correct using `checkCredentials` method. If it returns null, than user name or password are incorrect. Otherwise `UserDetails` object, which contains `info` will be returned.

Code in main method will look like

```
final UserService userService = new UserService();
//...read from cmd
UserService.UserDetails details = userService.checkCredentials(username, password);
if (details == null) {
    System.out.println("ACCESS DENIED");
} else {
    System.out.println("WELCOME");
}
```

Comment: From the main method `UserService.UserDetails details = userService.checkCredentials(username, password);`, it says it can't find variable username (or password) in the main class.

Comment: `//...read from cmd` copy your code which receives `String username;` and `String password;` from command line there